# Nginx: Rewriting existing directives in ./conf.d/*.conf

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, webserver

When I setup my `Nginx` I do not change `nginx.conf` so it it will be easier to update software (same goes for mysql, php, etc.).

Until now I needed just to add new directives to my configs but now for first time I need to change directive that exists in `nginx.conf` - I want to change `sendfile on` to `off`, so it solves `VirtualBox` [shared folders bug](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html).

When I try to do this I get an error `2015/10/18 23:04:50 [emerg] 3699#0: "sendfile" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/my.conf:1`

So what to do? Is actually editing `nginx.conf` my only option?